# Twitter Bot To Post Random Tweets on Twitter(X) AuthV2 from Node.js

Tags: node.js, twitter, tweets

I have a Node.js code which is working at present to post a Tweet, but I need it to post a random one from a list.  I see there are a lot of examples of this from the previous API V1 of Twitter but it needs to work with the latest V2...

Here is my code which is working to post one Tweet("Hello World!"):

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: __dirname + "/.env" });
const { twitterClient } = require("./twitterClient.js")
const CronJob = require("cron").CronJob;

const tweet = async () => {
  try {
    await twitterClient.v2.tweet("Hello World!");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

const cronTweet = new CronJob("* * * * *", async () => {
  tweet();
});

cronTweet.start();
```

Comment: If you can send a tweet what’s the underlying issue? Picking a random element from an array?

Comment: Yes I need it to pick a random tweet from a pre-defined list... I've seen other examples on Google where the code calls a text file with the list of tweets in but I've tried those and they seem to throw an error saying they aren't compatible with Twitter API V2...... At least I can get this one to post a Tweet which is a start. (I'm completely new to Node.Js as well but I got it to post a Tweet.

Comment: Getting a string to tweet, and sending that tweet, are completely separate things; the Twitter API has nothing to do with the first part and cannot affect it. Maybe it’d make sense to first select from a hard-coded array, then move on to file IO.

Comment: OK Thanks, I'll have to look at this when I have a lot more time. I'm not a professional coder but I'm pretty good on computers using my initiative....  if there was a way I could choose from an array in the existing code that would be easiest.... is there a way to do that in Node.js?

Comment: I wondered if there was a way to spin the Tweet, like you used to get in those old Regex scripts....  something like this?:            await twitterClient.v2.tweet("Hello World!/Good Morning!/Good Evening!");                 that wouldn't require extra files

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "those old regex scripts", and it seems like a JS tutorial would be a better starting point than SO. To pick a random element from `const arr = ["Hello World!", "Good Morning!", "etc...."]` use any of the solutions duplicated here on SO or on the net, roughly `const randomEl = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]`

Comment: Thanks so much, that looks promising, I will try that and comeback tomorrow and let you know if it works

Comment: How would I insert -  const arr = ["Hello World!", "Good Morning!", "etc...."]     into:  const tweet = async () => {
  try {
    await twitterClient.v2.tweet("Newest Channel");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

Comment: In case somebody is searching for a similar solution, my node.js code just seemed to start working to post the "random" tweet.... I think it was blocked due to too many requests yesterday while testing.  It appears that a combination of this code I found on Gitkub does the trick: https://github.com/lazarkulasevic/twitter-bot/tree/main/data in his case he is pulling a random question.  It works with V2Auth API from Twitter

Comment: A blocked request would return an appropriate error response, viewable in the console and network tabs. I really think a tutorial would be a good idea—there’s no way in which the Twitter API version affects selecting a random string.

Comment: Yes it was returning a "Too Many Requests" Error in the terminal until the next day when I noticed the Github code above works. Thanks for all the help, I hope somebody finds this helpful